# Declare an cookie at server-side and use it at client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, cookies

Well , I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 RAZOR PAGE , and I declare a cookie from server-side:

```
@{
Request.Cookie["Name1"].Value = "Value1";
}
```

and, when I want to use and change it at client side , it working dubious

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
var e
 function aa(c) { $.cookie("Name1", c); }

 function bb() { e = $.cookie("Name1"); }

</script>
```

It`s something wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you need to set the cookie on the response, not on the request:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(CookieName);
myCookie.Values["UserId"] = user.UserId.ToString();
myCookie.Values["LastVisit"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```